# How to use a viewResolver using spring-rest?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am very much new to Spring-rest. I have small doubt on that.

In normal spring MVC we can get a response and we will display on the client side, for this, we are using view resolvers, to achieve this we have to do configurations on, XML file. but, in spring-rest, we know that HTTPMessageConverters ( are using for converting HTTP request to java object and object to HTTP response body.), here we can use REST-CLIENT for Testing Purpose.

Here is my question, **in spring MVC we can transfer the response to the particular page, but here means in spring-rest how to send it to particular client pages**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Kishorekumar. Please refer [How do I ask a good question on StackOverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any view resolver because you must respect the standard response with JSON or XML format for example. The important thing here it's not the page format, but the **content**. You can return directly an instance of type `ResponseEntity` or even a class that you define.

Here the example of the [doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

> Spring uses the Jackson JSON library to automatically marshal instances of type Greeting into JSON.

In this example, you don't need to take care of the format, because Spring is going to return a JSON by default.

Here an interesting blog that explains [REST architecture](https://www.sitepoint.com/developers-rest-api/).

Comment: Thanks , now i got clarification